# Swift wait for async task

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

In a background thread we have:

```
defer {
    cleanup()
}

loadData()

if error {
    return
}

processData()

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delay) {  //Delay = now + 0-2 seconds
     updateUI()
}
```

The problem is we want to ensure that the defer `cleanUp()` code runs after `updateUI()`.  And as it stands this won't happen as `updateUI()` runs async.

My thought was to sleep/block for that delay period instead of running asynchronously.  This would have the defer `cleanUp()` run once `updateUI()` is done.

How can you do this?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: You can `Thread.sleep()`, but there's serious code smell to that. We generally want to avoid blocking a thread (even a background one) for any period of time (or, at the very least, for more than a few milliseconds). Needless to say, never `sleep` on the main thread.

Comment: I don't quite get the gist of what you're saying: you want to do something functionally equivalent to: `sleep(delay); DispatchQueue.main.async { doStuff() }`?

Comment: @joeybladb I updated the description to give more context.

Comment: I gather that `processData` is asynchronous? If so, give it a completion handler closure parameter and call the `updateUI` from there. But don't `sleep` or use `asyncAfter`.

Comment: `processData` is not async.  All the code in the method is run in an async method.

Comment: If the issue is just that `updateUI()` is asynchronous, it should have a completion block where you can call `cleanup()`.

Comment: That is the issue.  Ok I could do that.  I was looking to just have `cleanup()` called from defer and not have two calls to it.  But I suppose it doesn't matter.

Comment: "The problem is we want to ensure that the defer `cleanUp()` code runs after `updateUI()`." Then why doesn't the `asyncAfter` block say `updateUI(); cleanUp()` ?? That ensures it.

Comment: Do.Not.Wait. Get used to the asynchronous pattern. That's *the better way*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized I could just change the structure of the code:

```
loadData()

if error {
    log.error("Error")
} else {
   processData()
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delay) {  //Delay = now + 0-2 seconds
  updateUI()
  cleanup()
}
```

Comment: A hard-coded delay is very bad programming habit and is not 100% reliable. Why don't you update the UI in the completion handler of the asynchronous task?

Comment: Did that.  Thanks.

Comment: @MarcusLeon You don't need the delay when you update the UI in the completionhandler, unless you want the user to wait for a couple more seconds.

Comment: Yes that's the goal actually..  the `processData()` can complete very quickly..  and we show a refresh indicator which appears to flicker when the method completes quickly.  So we set a min time of 1.25 seconds which is what the `delay` is about.

Comment: @MarcusLeon I see. For those purposes that works fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a semaphore to tell the cleanup task to wait until `updateUI` has completed:

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
defer {
    semaphore.wait()
    cleanup()
}

loadData()

if error {
    // If we exit here, the semaphore would have never been used
    // and cleanup will run immediately
    return
}

processData()
semaphore.wait() // here, we claim the semaphore, making cleanup
                 // wait until updateUI is done
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delay) {
     updateUI()
     semaphore.signal()
}
```

Comment: Thanks- is using DispatchGroup (enter leave wait) another way of implementing this?

Comment: Yes, you can also implement it using `DispatchGroup`. I'm on a project that make heavy use of semaphore right now so I'm a bit biased :)

Comment: Thanks.   I like these options but realized I could just restructure the code to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

An other alternative is using `DispatchGroup()`:

```
func doWork() {

   let group = DispatchGroup()

   group.enter() //Enter #1
   loadData { result in

      switch (result) {
      case .success(_):
           group.enter()//Enter #2
           processData { group.leave()//Leave #2 }
      case .failure(let error):
           //Do something nice with the error
           print(error)
      }

      group.leave()//Leave #1
    }

    //All the code inside this block will be executed on the mainThread when all tasks will be finished.
     group.notify(queue: .main) { [weak self] in

         guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

         strongSelf.updateUI()
         strongSelf.cleanup()
     }
}

private func updateUI() {
    //All your stuff
}

private func cleanup() {
    //All your stuff
}

private func loadData(completion: (Result<(), Error>) -> ()) {
    //All your stuff
    if error {
       completion(.failure(error))
    }
    else {
       completion(.success(()))
    }
}

private func processData(completion: () -> ()) {
    //All your stuff
    completion()
}
```