# How to use async-http-client

Tags: swift, swift-nio

I am trying to execute the example of `async-http-client` doku. But unfortunately the code in the closure is not executed. Why?

```
import AsyncHTTPClient

let httpClient = HTTPClient(eventLoopGroupProvider: .createNew)
httpClient.get(url: "https://swift.org").whenComplete { result in
    print (result)
    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        print("failure")
    case .success(let response):
        if response.status == .ok {
            print("success")
        } else {
            print("error in response")
        }
    }
}
```

In the console I get: *`Program ended with exit code: 0`*. So it is executed with success. But there is no print statement in the console.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the main thread is getting executed before the request is done so no print statement will get called unless you ask the main thread to wait for the httpclient

https://github.com/swift-server/async-http-client/issues/129

Comment: Ok thanks. I saw it. I had to call it in such a manner:
```
import AsyncHTTPClient
let httpClient = HTTPClient(eventLoopGroupProvider: .createNew)
let response = try httpClient.get(url: "https://swift.org").wait()
print (response)
```
So if I like to create a Swift Server script that makes remote calls, I have to handle them in a sequential(synchronous) way or how can I implement it in a asynchronous way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568614/swift-wait-for-async-task?rq=1 check this way to wait for async tasks so you can run multiple tasks at the same time but you can't run it without waiting all tasks in the main thread